# Adding leading zeros to the value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add leading zeros to the meta_value of every entry with the meta_key "_recommended" (see screenshot)? So for example I would need the meta_value of this 4 entries replaced with 000023, 000015, 000011 with an SQL command.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LPAD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
SELECT LPAD(meta_value, 6, '0')
FROM yourtablename
WHERE meta_key = '_recommended'
```

To update your table with the new values, just use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourtablename
SET meta_value = LPAD(meta_value, 6, '0')
WHERE meta_key = '_recommended'
```

Comment: I get a list with the right values now after I use this command in phpmyadmin, but I don't know how to overwrite the old existing values. Sorry, I'm a total beginner in MySQL.

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite them with the new leading zeros?

Comment: yes I would like to overwrite the old values with the new values. But if I use the above command it only shows a list with the values I need. But I want this values to be in my DB (old entries overwritten)